# how to test that props are passed to child component with react testing library and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

i am new to react and react testing. i want to test that props are passed to child component.how should i do it??

```
import React from 'react'

import { SubsectionTitle } from 'LookingGlass/common/components'

import constants from 'LookingGlass/constants'

import SelectorIPVersion from 'LookingGlass/app/components/SelectorIPVersion'
import SelectorNetwork from 'LookingGlass/app/components/SelectorNetwork'
import SelectorRouter from 'LookingGlass/app/components/SelectorRouter'

export default function QueryPanelRouters(props = {}) {
  const { env, query, isLoading = false } = props

  const disabled = isLoading

  const onIPVersionChanged = (selectedVersion) =>
    (query.ipVersion = selectedVersion)
  const ipVersionProps = {
    checkedVersion: query.ipVersion,
    onChange: onIPVersionChanged,
    disabled,
  }

  const onNetworkChanged = (selectedNetwork) =>
    (query.network = selectedNetwork)
  const networkProps = {
    selectedNetwork: query.network,
    onChange: onNetworkChanged,
    disabled,
  }

  const onRouterChanged = (selectedRouter) => (query.router = selectedRouter)
  const routerProps = {
    selectedRouter: query.router,
    onChange: onRouterChanged,
    disabled,
    routers: env.routers
      ? env.routers.filter((router) => router.network === query.network)
      : [],
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SubsectionTitle text={constants.QueryPanelRouters.title} />
      <SelectorIPVersion {...ipVersionProps} />
      <SelectorNetwork {...networkProps} />
      <SelectorRouter {...routerProps} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

i have no idea how to write test for passing props to child component.thanks in advance.

Comment: yes Thank you for answer!!

Comment: [How can I test if prop is passed to child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939196/how-can-i-test-if-a-prop-is-passed-to-child) This solved my problem